# Autoplay Youtube video in modal? (Avada Wordpress theme)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, youtube, bootstrap-modal

Hello again SO community! I have a Wordpress site using the Avada theme which comes with an out-of-the-box modal element within its native "Fusion Builder" page builder. I have embedded a YouTube video within the modal using an iframe code, and have linked the modal to a "play" button on my homepage. Currently, you have to press the "play" button on to initiate the popup (modal) and then press play again to begin the video. I would like the video to begin playing immediately upon opening in the modal window so that users don't have to press play twice. I'm finding that this is more difficult than I thought it would be.

This is my website: http://8d2.b73.myftpupload.com/

I don't know how to write jquery, only HTML and CSS. However, I am somewhat familiar with reading jquery. I'm currently using this code (below) which I got from another SO search. It is not working. I'm using a plugin to insert the code into the header.

```
var videoSrc = $("#homepage-video iframe").attr("src");

$('#homepage-video').on('show.bs.modal', function () { // on opening the modal
// set the video to autostart
$("#homepage-video iframe").attr("src", videoSrc+"&amp;autoplay=1");
});

$("#homepage-video").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) { // on closing the modal
// stop the video
$("#homepage-video iframe").attr("src", null);
});
```

Here is my modal HTML code, although I'm using the page builder to create and manage the modal, which technically uses shortcode, so I do not really see or do anything with this code:

```
<div class="fusion-modal modal fade modal-1 homepage-video" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-1" aria-hidden="true" id="homepage-video" style="display: none;">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content fusion-modal-content" style="background-color:#f6f6f6">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-heading-1" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" data-fontsize="25" data-lineheight="31"></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p><iframe src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/BLFCOVea3yU?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if Avada natively uses bootstrap -- I'm not sure what the theme is built on. So, just in case my jquery code is not working because the theme is not using bootstrap, I inserted the following into the header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

My jquery looks correct from what I am able to read, and it seems like everything is set up properly. Nothing is working, though. Any code geniuses out there see the issue?

Comment: UPDATE: Turns out code isn't needed for this at all, which is great! See answer below and be sure to read the comments for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select The Modal Module from the Avada [ Fusion Builder ]. Then you need to select "Fusion Builder" in Contents of Modal and select Youtube from the options comes. You need to Select the option Autoplay Yes from Youtube option.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: The Modal element (Fusion Builder) only has a text box for "modal content" and thus doesn't let you embed other elements unless you use HTML or shortcode. I was using an iframe embed code in the content box before, but after reading this answer, I tried using shortcode from the YouTube element instead, and it worked!!!

Comment: Just to be clear for other people who may struggle with this same issue, you have to first create a Modal element, then create a YouTube video element. Enter the details for your video, and make sure autoplay is toggled on. Then switch the page to "default view" so that it converts everything into shortcode. Find the shortcode for your YouTube video element and copy it. Switch back to Fusion Builder, and then paste the shortcode into the "modal content" box within the Modal element. You can delete the YouTube video element you created (only used to get shortcode). Use CSS to style as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
$("iframe#divID").attr("src", $("iframe#divID").attr("src").replace("autoplay=0", "autoplay=1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Riffing off another answer, I actually had to go to fusion builder element generator within the modal builder (to be able to put in code for example) :
[image]